# Array Split comma separated on certain key

Tags: php, arrays

Wondering if I can get some assistance.

I've got an array that looks like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Model X, Model S, Model 3
        [1] => Tesla
        [2] => Elon Musk
    )
)
```

I'd like to create another array (split on key[0] with a comma), like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Model X
        [1] => Tesla
        [2] => Elon Musk
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Model S
        [1] => Tesla
        [2] => Elon Musk
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Model 3
        [1] => Tesla
        [2] => Elon Musk
    )
)
```

Hope this makes sense, would appreciate some assistance.

Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you having? Just call `explode()` on `$val[0]`, then loop through that and push the arrays onto the result array.

Comment: Also, I am sure in your real array you have quotes around the strings (this note is for inexperienced readers)

Comment: @Barmar, ok using explode(), but I don't really know how I can push it back and copy all other values into the array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `explode`, `array_slice` and `array_merge` functions:

```
$arr = [0 => ['Model X, Model S, Model 3', 1 => 'Tesla', 2 => 'Elon Musk']];
$model_info = array_slice($arr[0], 1);  // model's additional  info
$result = [];

foreach (explode(",", $arr[0][0]) as $model) {
    $result[] = array_merge([$model], $model_info);
}
// now $result contains the expected array
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The array in the example has only three values but the one I am working on has many more. I need to slice the values in more then one occasion in the same array but the sliced value replaces the value of zero but not the one I am actually slicing. Is there a way to control that?

Comment: @devofash, want some new solution? update your question with new input array and respective expected result

Answer (score 1):

Here's your solution.

```
$Array=array(array('Model X, Model S, Model 3','Tesla','Elon Musk'));

$Unfold1=explode(',',$Array[0][0]);

foreach($Unfold1 AS $Data){
   $Response[]=array($Data,$Array[0][1],$Array[0][2]);
}
print_r($Response);
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh. Appreciate it.

Comment: Mark  your question as closed please.